# Загрузить .obj с сервера ( как лучше сделать)

Tags: c#, unity3d

На сервере есть 3d объекты, например, кувшин, ручка от кувшина и т.д.

Пользователь может кастомизировать объект как угодно, например, приделать ручку или нет, повернуть ручку как угодно, засунуть ручку в кувшин и т.д

Далее генерируется на сервере .obj и я в юнити его распарсиваю вместе с текстурами.

Далее строится модель, создаются текстуры, нормал мап и материал и это все сетится модели.

Проблема в том что это все очень долго происходит( от 40 секунд и выше.) делаю под мобилки.

Если ли какойто другой способ это сделать (более быстрый)?

Или все файлы, текстуры, нормал мапы и т.д. хранить в юнити, а с сервера передавать индекс материала и расположение 3д объектов( например расположение ручки на кувшине, ротэйшн) ведь оно может быть разное.

Что кто посоветует?

Comment: 1. Не делать на мобилки. 2. Воспользоваться возможностями параллельного программирования. 3. Оптимизировать все циклы по генерации данных. 4. А зачем объект хранить на сервере? Обычно на клиенте все хранится, а сервер только команды посылает.

Comment: Мне как раз нужно под мобилки. 3. В нэте нашёл самый лучший objLoader, там думаю все ок с оптимизацией. 4. Это изначально вэб приложение никак не связанное с юнити. Там все хранится. Юнити нужен для AR, который захотели вдруг при делать. В итоге, я беру сгенерированный .obj, парсю и он доступен в юнити для AR. Кроме как оптимизировать нет вариантов?

Comment: А ты можешь на сервере что-то сделать ? поменять формат например ? или  в любом случае obj на вход ? или на строне сервера можно подготовить данные ?

Comment: На сервере все уже хранится и настроено в .obj. 
Но допустим если web приложение переписать и файлы будут в другом формате, их тоже надо будет парсить в юнити? А заранее подготовить не могу, так как не извесно какая будет модель(где, например, будет расположена ручка у чашки) и т.д. + есть целый список текстур с нормалями и т.д. который можно применить к любому объекту отдельно.